# C++ IDE that can build over SSH

Tags: c++, ide, editor

We are moving our development for C to C++, but all build servers run Linux and development happens on Windows machines. Our C editor does not do C++ very well so we are looking at alternatives.

The code itself lives on the build server connected by `\\opt\code...` type link in Windows.

We need SSH as that is the normal connection to the build servers. We would like an integrated solution for errors/warnings being able to opened in the editor. We do not care about running the code.

Are there any free editors that can execute builds over SSH?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but are you searching for a fully fledged IDE or just a programmer editor? If you're looking just for an editor, I guess VIM can be a good answer, althou builds are managed via make. Or just putty on the linux box and run "make"

Comment: Looking for a solution that will aid productivity :) The aim is a nice editor that can do builds and show the results such that "double clicking" takes you to the error/warning. We already use the putty SSH -> run make util, but we find that dev teams do not like this as requires them to switch backwards and forwards with search for file(s) and lines, rather than just simple click (like VS).

Comment: I'd give a look to Eclipse. Has almost everything also for C/C++ builds and works with make. Btw, seems that long are the days when to make a dev happy just the words VI or EMACS where enough.

Comment: The first paragraph of your question suggests that you already have an editor that does what you need, but that it doesn't work well with C++. What editor is that?

Comment: CodeWrite - it has support but not great.

Comment: @BigMike - Eclipse is something we want to steer away from. The dev machines are fairly low spec. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: You said: *We already use the putty SSH -> run make util.* Since you already have a Windows command line that runs the remote make, it should be possible to run that same command line as the build instructions inside of the Zeus IDE and then navigate the results of the build from inside of Zeus. But Zeus is not free. There is also a *ZeusLite* that is free and it should also be able to do something similar - http://zeusedit.com

Comment: @jussij - Sorry, what we currently do is open a putty window on the server and execute make there. It's not a windows command unfortunately.

Comment: As per @jussij suggestion, can't you use something like plink to run the renote command line (i.e. use -batch mode) - http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NetBeans allows to build over ssh. We are using this from Linux development computers to linux build machines. I am not sure if this is possible from Windows to Linux. Here is a tutorial: [Tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks - although we were trying to stay away from Java based IDEs, it is nice to know that it works. The build and integration seem quite good. Now if only doing alt-tab would not keep selecting File when pressed... :)

Comment: After using NetBeans for a couple of weeks now, it appears like it will meet our needs quite well...even though it is java :)

Comment: Yes, with Netbeans it is possible to build over ssh from windows to linux!

Comment: I was going to use NetBeans for this very nice feature. However, I discovered that there is no way ever, at all, to `source` a script before building. This made NetBeans very impractical for many serious projects. It's quite a shame that it solely depends on lame unix makefiles in 2017 still.

Answer (score 6):

This [link suggest](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) this should be possible using **plink** and any editor that can run plink as a compile and capture the resulting stdio and stderr output.

Comment: Yes, plink appears to work. This does open a few doors, but then the "point and click" integration needs to be coded into editor. But this is quite useful for some other automation's :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Visual Slick Edit](http://www.slickedit.com/) it has a scripting language which can be used to spawn commands. Btw, if your build is linux based I suggest you to edit on linux (there're various programmers editors there available for free).

In windows almost every editor worth being calling editor has the power to manage builds (often via make), so even VIM or Emacs can be productivity choices (yeah I'm not a big fans of IDEs, my actual editor is VIM with a good tons of vimscripts and yeah, I've got code navigation, error browsing and the speed of light while typing - and the same is possible with emacs).

Ultraedit is another editor able to Edit file over ftp (and maybe over SSH), but I doubt it can spawn a remote make and fetch results.

If you're not reliyng on builds, but just compiling, maybe is worth checking the Cygwin porject and see if you can arrange a compilation under Windows, then for the build manually resort to the Linux box, this would probably remove the compilation problem (every programmer will compile on his box, and only builds (compile+link) would be left on the linux box.

Comment: Thanks - Cygwin is an option, but not look keen moving an existing database of files, etc. VIM and EMACS are just too much typing for me :) I'm a point & click guy :P

Answer (score 1):

You might use X forwarding and run any linux IDE on the Linux side, while operating it via Windows machines. See http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html for an example.

Or even setup a VNC remote desktop connection.

Comment: X11 forwarding does not appear to be working properly. Xming does not want to connect...maybe a server setting...

Comment: We considered VNC but in a multi user environment, the shared screen etc. does not play well. We use it on other servers but the complaints about someone kicking someone else off goes round the office from time to time :(

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this, but it looks like that using Code::Blocks and Xming you can do this.
Here is tutorial http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_Xming_for_remote_compilation

Comment: Unfortunately all I get is `Process terminated with status 1`. There's no useful debug from CB to say what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Dokan SSHFS](http://dokan-dev.net/en/) to mount the code as a drive on each Windows machine.  Then developers are free to use whatever IDE they choose.

Comment: How does that help to invoke the compiler on the Linux build server? The question wasn't about how to mount the file system.